# C#, byte arrays, avoid memory fragmentation

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-fragmentation

I'm writing a data structure, which main purpose will be containing binary data (byte arrays) organized in such way, that user can insert data in the middle without performance penalties (moving large chunks of memory).

For that purpose, I'll need to create a lot of smaller byte-arrays, which will serve as buffers for parts of the bigger structure. The problem is that I might need to juggle those small arrays frequently and I'm worried about possible memory fragmentation.

My idea to avoid it is to ensure, that all arrays I use within this structure will have one of two sizes, say 1024 or 2048 bytes (or similar, generally n and 2*n). I hope to simplify work of memory manager, which will be able to reuse memory after disposed arrays.

Will it work that way? Or should I design some kind of array pool and implement the array-reusing mechanism myself?

Comment: a: `ArrayPool<byte>` and `MemoryPool<byte>` are your friend; b: don't forget you can lease from *larger* arrays and use `ArraySegment<byte>` or `Memory<byte>` to represent the individual slices - it *may* be easier to just rent reasonable sized blocks, though; keep in mind that `ArrayPool<byte>` can issue over-sized arrays, so you'd need to use something like `ArraySegment<byte>` or `Memory<byte>` *anyway*

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but also consider taking a step back and whether it's possible to have an architecture where clients only write data moving forward, with (constant sized) length prefixes to allow readers to skip data they're not interested in. This is vastly simpler than efficiently juggling multiple buffers.

Comment: additional thought: if you're essentially building things akin to streams: consider `ReadOnlySequence<byte>`. This is a chain of discontiguous buffer segments; you can implement your own sequence very easily, then you can break the chain at any point, insert a range, and fix-up the chain; it is just a linked-list with some offset data in each

Comment: There is no *generic* solution to the question of fragmentation.  It has plagued OS developers from the beginning.  Their solution was different pool sizes, and preallocation of fixed sized buffers.